# Is there a way to visualize my data into a table format in R

Tags: r

I am trying to visualize my data into a table format. Is there a package in R that can do this for me and how would I implement it.

My table looks like this:

```
Audubon_01      
18 - 24 6   11
25 - 34 29  23
35 - 44 25  17
45 - 54 28  22
55 - 64 52  39
65 and Over 154 124


Audubon_02      
18 - 24 9   6
25 - 34 24  21
35 - 44 12  16
45 - 54 31  18
55 - 64 53  34
65 and Over 132 94


Boone_BN1       
18 - 24 6   6
25 - 34 43  29
35 - 44 50  37
45 - 54 37  23
55 - 64 69  42
65 and Over 115 73


Boone_BN2       
18 - 24 19  17
25 - 34 32  34
35 - 44 39  25
45 - 54 30  24
55 - 64 77  31
65 and Over 136 78


Boone_BN3       
18 - 24 7   4
25 - 34 42  33
35 - 44 42  32
45 - 54 41  24
55 - 64 64  40
65 and Over 118 72


Boone_BN4       
18 - 24 10  8
25 - 34 42  36
35 - 44 47  48
45 - 54 51  38
55 - 64 85  66
65 and Over 157 130
```

I would like my output to be in this format where I can control X amount of columns that will be used:

(apologies for miss alignment of data but I'm sure you can see the point)

```
Audubon_01              Audubon_02              Boone_BN1       
    Females Males           Females Males           Females Males
18 - 24 6   11      18 - 24 9   6       18 - 24 6   6
25 - 34 29  23      25 - 34 24  21      25 - 34 43  29
35 - 44 25  17      35 - 44 12  16      35 - 44 50  37
45 - 54 28  22      45 - 54 31  18      45 - 54 37  23
55 - 64 52  39      55 - 64 53  34      55 - 64 69  42
65 and Over 154 124     65 and Over 132 94      65 and Over 115 73


Boone_BN2               Boone_BN3               Boone_BN4       
    Females Males           Females Males           Females Males
18 - 24 19  17      18 - 24 7   4       18 - 24 10  8
25 - 34 32  34      25 - 34 42  33      25 - 34 42  36
35 - 44 39  25      35 - 44 42  32      35 - 44 47  48
45 - 54 30  24      45 - 54 41  24      45 - 54 51  38
55 - 64 77  31      55 - 64 64  40      55 - 64 85  66
65 and Over 136 78      65 and Over 118 72      65 and Over 157 130
```

Is there a package that would allow me to visualize it in a way where it could look like this? It is extremely time consuming to do this by hand in excel or numbers. :

(Using same names for columns and rows obviously this is just a visual aid for format)

[image: Ward breakout design]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution where you can paste together the different elements you want displayed (like in the image) and then reshape your data.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(age.group=sample(c(1:5),200,T),gender=sample(c('m','f'),200,T))
df2 <- data.frame(age.group=sample(c(1:5),200,T),gender=sample(c('m','f'),200,T))

bind_rows(df1 %>% mutate(df='One'),df2 %>% mutate(df='Two')) %>% 
  count(df,age.group,gender) %>% 
  mutate(row=paste0(age.group,' - ',gender,': ',n)) %>% 
  group_by(df) %>% mutate(r=seq(1:n())) %>% 
  select(df,r,row) %>% spread(df,row) %>% select(-r)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   One       Two      
   <chr>     <chr>    
 1 1 - f: 22 1 - f: 23
 2 1 - m: 24 1 - m: 18
 3 2 - f: 18 2 - f: 20
 4 2 - m: 22 2 - m: 17
 5 3 - f: 14 3 - f: 20
 6 3 - m: 23 3 - m: 23
 7 4 - f: 19 4 - f: 26
 8 4 - m: 15 4 - m: 17
 9 5 - f: 22 5 - f: 12
10 5 - m: 21 5 - m: 24
```